# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './templates'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have this javascript (TypeScript) file

index.ts

```
import 
'../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as templates from './templates';

document.body.innerHTML = templates.main;

const mainElement = 
document.body.querySelector('.b4.main');
const alertsElement = 
document.body.querySelector('.b4-alerts');

mainElement.innerHTML = templates.welcome;
alertsElement.innerHTML = templates.alert;
```

When I run my project (with webpack dev server) I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './templates' in '/Users/BorisGrunwald/Desktop/Node/b4-app/app'
```

I don't understand why it can't seem to find "templates.ts" since both files are in the same folder.

Here is a picture of my project structure:

[image]

My webpack config:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const distDir = path.resolve(__dirname,'dist');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

 module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: distDir
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase:distDir,
        port:60800
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Better Book Bundle Builder'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $:'jquery',
            jQuery:'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test:/\.ts$/,
            loader:'ts-loader'
        },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader']
        },{
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            loader:'url-loader?limit=100000'
        }]
    }
};
```

Templates.ts

```
export const main = `
    <div class="container">
        <h1>B4 - Book Bundler</h1>
        <div class="b4-alerts"></div>
        <div class="b4-main"></div>
    </div>
`;

export const welcome = `
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>B4 is an application for creating book bndles</p>
    </div>
`;

export const alert = `
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" 
role="alert">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong>Success!</strong> Bootstrap is working
    </div>
`;
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try if this works. This will allow importing from folder without the dots.

```
import {main, welcome, alert} from './templates';
```

Webpack does not look for `.ts` files by default. You can configure resolve.extensions to look for `.ts`. Don't forget to add the default values as well, otherwise most modules will break because they rely on the fact that the `.js` extension is automatically used.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
}
```

This goes for all other files too, for example `.scss` files etc. Error will be `SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.`

Comment: That was it! Really weird since webstorm is giving me the error "TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './templates' instead"